# Objective-c how to increase/decrease height of UITableViewCell on click of provided button on Celll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have UItable view cell on which there is a button.when I click on the that button particular
cell  should increase and display its 8 labels and when i click  again on button it should get its original shape.initially i want to display only two labels.
can anyOne  help me how should I proceed.

and I have tried like I created customized cell with 8 labels and one button.
I am trying to display cell with 8 labels when button is click otherwise  with two.which is not happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload a cell in your UITableView, use the following code:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

This will cause both your tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: methods to be called with the appropriate indexPath before the corresponding cell redraws. Make sure you keep track of whether the cell at that index path should be expanded or contracted (don't store that information in the cell itself, since you'll be creating a new cell), and respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for ur kind reply But if U provide me step by step solution for my problem it will be nice for me,I have got this problem   first time and I don't  know how to start ,any tutorial/code for this kind of problem will be ok...thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method linked to the button on cell should be like this :

```
- (IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender;
```

In its implementation you could try this :

```
UIButton *button=sender;
UITableViewCell *cell=[button superview]; //this should get you the contentView OR the UITableViewCell
//now you can increase cell to display all its content
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[cell setFrame:yourFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I'm not sure that `[button superview]` get the table cell or the property contentView of the cell because now i cannot try this code.